# Alexa skill Audio Directives - ENQUEUE is not working

Tags: audio, alexa-skills-kit

My initial play command works fine and my Next Intent works fine. But ENQUEUE does not work. Nothing plays after my first song is finished. 
Here is the request that I am receiving from Alexa

```
    {
    "Token": "31|f2a55190-c12b-4a28-8e57-bfe1c36581f5|838",
    "OffsetInMilliseconds": 0,
    "Type": "AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished",
    "Context": null,
    "RequestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.aa961d0b-cc62-4921-a674-b8c2e00e0d22",
    "Timestamp": "2017-02-19T04:34:33Z"
}
```

Below is the response that I am sending

```
{
    "Card": null,
    "OutputSpeech": null,
    "Reprompt": null,
    "ShouldEndSession": true,
    "Directives": [{
        "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
        "playBehavior": "ENQUEUE",
        "audioItem": {
            "stream": {
                "token": "32|f2a55190-c12b-4a28-8e57-bfe1c36581f5|839",
                "expectedPreviousToken": "32|f2a55190-c12b-4a28-8e57-bfe1c36581f5|838",
                "url": "https://www.example.com/music/test/mysong.mp3",
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I can't figure out why the next song is not playing
Thanks

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I've been having a similar issue where the ENQUEUE will work a few times, and then randomly it won't work. It will get to he end of the track and the next enqueued song just won't play. And then when I reopen the skill and try and play the track again it says "There was a problem with the requested skill response". The randomness of it is what confuses me. In one instance it it will enqueue correctly twice and break the 3rd time. In another it will enqueue correctly 10 times and break on the eleventh.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on skill that heavily uses audio directives. I can't tell that much from the response. But here is my 2cents. You have to make sure that expectedPreviousToken is correct. It should be the same token that was played earlier.